# What is the best category/site for asking a question about configuring computer peripherals?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm thinking either server-fault or superuser, but not sure.

Here's the question I'm interested in finding a home for:

I'd like to know if anyone has had experience connecting the Ipevo VZ-1 (http://support.ipevo.com/support/qa/IPEVO-VZ-1-HD-VGA-USB-Document-Camera)  wirelessly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Comment: @gnat: that post doesn't address using peripherals; that's an end-user question (so Super User, or for Apple hardware / software, Ask Differently).

Comment: @MartijnPieters good catch, thanks! (retracted my dupe vote)

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking in a personal capacity or the hardware is aimed at the general consumer then [Super User](http://superuser.com) is the site you want.

If you are asking in a professional capacity and the hardware is aimed at the business/corporate consumer then [Server Fault](http://servfault.com) *may* be more appropriate.

The best advice is to read the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://superuser.com/help) pages for the site and if you are still confused ask on their [Meta](https://superuser.com/meta).

In your case, I'd say that Super User was the site you need.